# For which purpose processRequest method is used in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

**How can I handle my requests through processRequest in Servlet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans generates this method. This method does not exist in servlet API. You can handle get or post method through it.

Comment: You can handle any request through it actually.

Comment: @EJP and user3260147 how can I handle get or POST request through it.Can you explain?

Comment: @TruePS It already happens. Have a look at the generated code.

Comment: @EJP i didn't understand it from Netbeans that's why i Came here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

clic on the sign + right under processRequest
[just click on the sign +](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkwmE.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Could you post the image instead of linking it?